# How to download a PDF file in a Shiny app

Tags: r, download, shiny

I have one PDF in the www directory of my shiny app. I would like that file to be available for download. How can i do that.

The download example works well, but no idea to use it for PDF download from www directory.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look in the `downloadHandler` function [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html), it has two arguments without default values: filename and content.

**filename** is basically the name of the file that will be downloaded. It has not to be inside a function. `filename = "your-pdf-name.pdf"` works as much as defining it inside the argumentless function.

**content**, in the other hand, creates a tempfile with the content that is going to be downloaded. In most cases you're going to create a file that is going to be fulfilled with something you have created in you app.

How that is not your case, my solution provides something we call "gambiarra" in Brasil: it copies the file you want to download to the tempfile that shiny needs to the `downloadHandler` works. (I've tried just define it as the path to the file but it doesn't work)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "your-pdf-name.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("www/teste.pdf", file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this work with other file formats as well? I am trying this solution with a ".docx" right now and not getting my file to download.

Comment: It surely does. I would advice you to open a question with a reprex of your problem.

Comment: Pay attention that this folder may be write protected if hosted on a server. It's better to use temp files if you use `downloadHandler`

Comment: @Billy34 that must be whats happening to me, the downloaded file I get is of a weird type, just like it is protected or something (a lock appears in the icon of the download). If you could help me out I just posted a question about it.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is in the `www` folder then you simply have to provide a link to it in the UI

```
... (in UI)
  tags$a("Click here to get the PDF", href="your-pdf-name.pdf")
...
```

If the filename is not known at start time then use uiOutput/renderUI and set rv$filename to the filename when you generate it.

```
... (in UI)
  uiOutput("dlURL")
...


... (in server)
  rv <- reactiveValues(filename="")

  output$dlURL <- renderUI({
    tags$a("Click here to get the file", href=rv$filename)
  })
...
```

Comment: One year later, but I don't really know what is the www folder, is it the same folder that contains the app in my computer? Should I include the file I want to be downloaded inside my code somehow?

Comment: Hello. The www folder is a subfolder of your app folder. If it exists, it's content will be accessible from the browser. It's useful for instance for assets such as images, stylesheet, scripts or static documents (e.g. reports, manual, ...)

Comment: Thanks! How do I access this www folder tho, should I create a folder called www? I want to make it possible for the user to download an existing file just like this example, the only difference is I have a .xlsx file not pdf.

Comment: yes create a folder www in your app folder, put your xlsx file in it and put `tags$a("Click here to get the XLSX", href="your-pdf-name.xlsx")` in the UI where you want your user to click to download it

Comment: This worked great!  My app helps the user to create certain files of interest.  Then I use my package shinyDebuggingPanel (on github), open up an interactive R box with control-D, and paste in:

system('cp file-to-download www')

tags$a("Click here to get the file", href="file-to-download")

click and !voila! here it is: file is in Downloads.
PS:  I use shinyDebuggingPanel a LOT.

Answer (score 0):

*(Adding again in "Your Answer"... to use the formatting.)*
@Bill34 gave me the answer I need. This post extends the idea.

My app helps the user to create certain files of interest.
Then I use my package [shinyDebuggingPanel](https://github.com/professorbeautiful/shinyDebuggingPanel) (on github), open up an interactive R box with control-D, and paste in:

```
system('cp file-to-download www') 
tags$a("Click here to get the file", href="file-to-download")
```

click and !voila! here it is: file-to-download is in your local Downloads folder.

PS: I use shinyDebuggingPanel a LOT.
Forgot to make the www folder? No problem!
Control-D to open shinyDebuggingPanel,
and paste in
`system('mkdir www')`