# r Shiny:how to place downloadable PDF on app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a PDF that I want to place on the shiny app for users to download. The PDF is in the www directory of my app and is called documentation.pdf.  I found this answer: [How to download a PDF file in a Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420450/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-a-shiny-app/40422604) and tried to use the answer but my PDF would not download.

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "documentation.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("www/documentation.pdf", file)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you been looking at your app in the viewer or browser? For downloading csv files from shiny, it won't work if you have just run your app through the viewer. In the top left of the shiny app, there should be a button called like "Browser" and then the download works. This might be the same for pdfs but I'm not sure

Comment: I am running it on my browser