# Make my existent Excel file available for users to download in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, download

In my app, users should insert some data from an Excel file, but I want to make it possible for them to download one (TesteR.xlsx) in their computer and use it as an example. I have tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420450/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-a-shiny-app/65892688?noredirect=1#comment126414737_65892688) solution but it didn't work, when I click the button it downloads a kinda weird file.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadOP", label = "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$downloadOP <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "ph1data",
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("www/TesteR.xlsx", file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also included the file in a www folder like suggested in the other question, but maybe I am missing something.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `www` folder is in the same directory as your `app.r` or `server.r/ui.r` files. It must be readable by the shiny server.

As you don't state how your app is started/served (from your computer, on a server, what kind of server, using shiny/server, on shinyapps.io, shinyproxy, ...) further advice won't be very useful.

I will also add the file extension to `filename = "ph1data.xlsx"`.

If you add a `A` tag to your UI, does it work ? (target="self" prevent opening a new tab)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadOP", label = "Download"),
  tags$a("Download", href="TesteR.xlsx", target="self")
)
```

If you put and image (eg `test.jpg`) in your `www` folder and add an `IMG` tag to your UI, does it show the image ?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadOP", label = "Download"),
  tags$a("Download", href="TesteR.xlsx", target="self", class="btn btn-primary"),
  tags$img(src="test.jpg")
)
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response! I created a new directory and tested the image stuff, it worked and then the download seems to be working now too! In this solution, what appears is a kind of a hyperlink to click download, do you know if there's a way to make it look like a button? Just for visual purposes really, as it is now functional.

Comment: add `class="btn btn-primary"` to the `tags$a`. It will render the link as a button thanks to CSS and Bootstrap (I updated my answer accordingly)