# Is there any way to create a screenshot or PDF?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

We have a shiny app and I'm looking for a way to create/download a screenshot (PNG, JPG) or export/download a PDF.
The optimum would be if this file only contains the visuals (green), but I'd also be quite happy if there is only a way to do this with full frame (yellow or full page).

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Like clicking on a button and the download starts.

---

## MWE

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

################################################################################
################################ S E R V E R ###################################
################################################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
  output$histogram = renderPlot(
    hist(faithful$eruptions, breaks=input$days_plot)
  )
  
  output$histogram2 = renderPlot(
    hist(faithful$eruptions, breaks=input$days_plot)
  )
  
  output$active_cases = DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars, selection = 'single', options=list(scrollX=TRUE))
  
})

################################################################################
#################################### U I #######################################
################################################################################

ui = shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title="just a test"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      #h3("Downstream", style="text-align:center; 
      #                        color:white;
      #                        background-color:red'"
      #   ),
      sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                  menuItem("Tab1", tabName="active_cases", icon = icon("magnifying-glass-location")),
                  menuItem("Tab2", tabName="archive", icon = icon("box-archive")),
                  menuItem("Configuration", sliderInput("days_plot", "Days into past", 1, 60, 30))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName="active_cases", shiny::h2("Active Cases"),
                fluidRow(
                  box(title="Table", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, div(DT::dataTableOutput("active_cases")))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  box(title="Visual1", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, plotOutput("histogram")),
                  box(title="Visual2", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, plotOutput("histogram2"))
                )
        ),
        tabItem(tabName="archive", shiny::h2("Archive"))
      )
    )
  )
)

################################################################################
################################### R U N ######################################
################################################################################

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Strongly related if not a duplicate: [How to download a pdf file in a Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40420450/903061). You have the code to create the plots, so you can create a PDF file of those plots using the `pdf()` function. Then you can make that file downloadable as per the link.

Comment: Try the **shinyscreenshot** package (on CRAN) or the [capture package](https://github.com/dreamRs/capture).

Comment: shinyscreenshot is exactly what I was looking for. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it as suggested (thank you very much, Stephane) with `shinyscreenshot`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyscreenshot)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(bslib)
library(plotly)

################################################################################
################################ S E R V E R ###################################
################################################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
  output$histogram = renderPlotly(
    ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=hp, color=gear)) + geom_point())
  )
  
  
  output$active_cases = DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars)
  
  ######################### SCREENSHOT REACTIVE FUNCTION #########################  
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    screenshot(id = "to_plot") # plot only ID "to_plot"
  })
  ######################### SCREENSHOT REACTIVE FUNCTION #########################
  
})


################################################################################
#################################### U I #######################################
################################################################################

ui = shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title="just a test"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                  menuItem("Tab1", tabName="active_cases", icon = icon("magnifying-glass-location"))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName="active_cases", shiny::h2("Active Cases"),
          fluidRow(actionButton("go", "go")),
              fluidRow(
                box(title="Table", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, div(DT::dataTableOutput("active_cases")))
              ),
          div(id="to_plot",
              fluidRow(
                box(title="Visual1", status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE, plotlyOutput("histogram"))
              )
          )
)))))


################################################################################
################################### R U N ######################################
################################################################################

shinyApp(ui, server)
```